# How do you mark code as deprecated in Go?

Tags: go

In Go, how do you mark code as deprecated so that users get a warning when using it?

Answer (score 164):

[Godoc: documenting Go code](http://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) says this about marking code as deprecated:

> To signal that an identifier should not be used, add a paragraph to its doc comment that begins with "Deprecated:" followed by some information about the deprecation.

Here's an example of the syntax (view more [here](https://github.com/golang/go/search?l=Go&q=Deprecated%3A&type=code)):

```
// Title treats s as UTF-8-encoded bytes and returns a copy with all Unicode letters that begin
// words mapped to their title case.                                                            
//                                                                         
// Deprecated: The rule Title uses for word boundaries does not handle Unicode              
// punctuation properly. Use golang.org/x/text/cases instead.                 
func Title(s []byte) []byte {  
    ⋮
}
```

The documentation site [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/) hides the documentation for deprecated identifiers behind a click of a "show" button.

The [staticcheck](https://staticcheck.io/) tool reports use of deprecated identifiers (see SA1019).

The [Goland IDE code inspector](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/code-inspections-in-go.html#General) reports use of deprecated identifiers.

Comment: This is the right way of doing it and should be marked as answer.  You can see the Go team using this pattern with `jpeg/Reader` as of Go 1.6: https://golang.org/src/image/jpeg/reader.go?s=2840:2891#L83 Later on, analyzer tools such as `godoc` and `golint` can be updated to detect this just as it does with the `Bug` doc definition: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc (see the `-notes` option).  BUGS and TODO don't normally show up in the documentation, unless you pass that flag and options.

Comment: These days `staticcheck` exists and will do this check, as `SA1019`

Answer (score 17):

Add this comment to your function / struct:

```golang
// Deprecated: FunctionName is deprecated.
```

Comment: Works in GoLand, IDE displays fieldname with a strikethrough style. Also a simple `// deprecated` comment the line before or at the same line of the definition worked for me.

Answer (score -6):

There is no support for this in the Go compiler (neither in 5g/6g/8g nor in gccgo).

As far as I know, there is currently no code checking tool for this.

The only way is to put the deprecation warning in documentation, or simply delete the code.

Comment: How about a way to insert warnings at all?  They could always go in the deprecated methods?